# Node.js: rerun the program when a file changes on a docker container

Tags: node.js, express, docker, nodemon

For my project I have done the following `Dockerfile` in order to have a base to develop node.js with express.js applications:

```
FROM node:alpine
MAINTAINER "Desyllas Dimitrios"

ENV NEO4J_HOST=""
ENV NEO4J_USER=""
ENV NEO4J_PASSWORD=""
ENV MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=""
ENV LOGS_DIR="/var/log/data_map"

COPY ./docker_scripts/entrypoint_dev.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    mkdir -p /opt/map &&\
    mkdir -p /var/log/data_map &&\
    chmod 0666 /var/log/data_map &&\
    npm install nodemon -g

EXPOSE 7474
VOLUME /var/log/data_map
VOLUME /opt/map

WORKDIR /opt/map

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon src/server.js"]
```

But over my project I have a folder containing twig templates, the folder is the `src/views` one. On my application I configurre the use of twig templates like this:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'twig');
app.set('twig options', {
    strict_variables: false
});
```

And over a route I use:

```
router.get('/my-route',function(req,res,next){
  res.render('my-route.html.twig',{
    'title': "Main Panel"
  });
});
```

My question is how I will make my docker image to rerun the app even when the template has been changed? With the current use I cannot restart my app when a change happens over a template in order to reload the new one.

Please keep in mind that I run my nodejs application with `nodemon` in order to rerun the application during the file changes when I develop my software.

## Edit 1:

What I want to do is to relaunch my application inside the container when I change over a template of even on frontend assets In the same way I relaunch it when I change server-side code.

Comment: Have you seen the api docs for the [fs library?](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) It fires an event whenever a watched file is updated, similarly to nodemon.

Comment: Well not exactly what I needed. It was my fault that I did not explained it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodemon allows you to specify [other extensions](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list) to watch other than just javascript.

Try changing

```
ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon src/server.js"]
```

To

```
ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon -e js,twig src/server.js"]
```

You may need to pass more file extensions in your arguments for your use case.